# with or without THE in “vexation of spirit”

Tags: definite-article

What are the differences:

> vexation of spirit

> the vexation of spirit

Consider this special context:
 
“Better is one handful of rest than two handfuls of toil and vexation of spirit.”

My understanding:

1, Because “rest” and “toil” do not have THE, vexation should not have THE so as to make it read better.

2, There might be something about the word “vexation” historically. But modern English would only say “the vexation of spirit”, because of the “the...of...” pattern.
 
(Or can you provide a modern English sentence where it is better to use “vexation of spirit”?)

Comment: How is this not editing? In any event, this is covered in many answers. Have you searched for X of Y?

Comment: *rest* and *toil* don't have "the" because they're being used as general concepts, not specific examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Vexation of spirit" is biblical and so old fashioned that it would be hard to find a modern English sentence using it.

[image]